# Validate that a Terraform variable is a list of alphanumeric strings

Tags: regex, validation, variables, terraform

I am trying to validate a variable in Terraform contains a list of alphanumeric strings. For this I'm using a regex and validating each element in the list matches this regex.

```
variable "list_of_strings" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "List of alphanumeric strings (case-insensitive)"

  validation {
    condition = can(all([
      for value in var.list_of_strings : can(regex("^[A-Za-z0-9]*$", value))
    ]))
    error_message = "list_of_strings must contain only alphanumeric strings (case-insensitive)."
  }
}
```

Then, when I generate a plan from this MWE with the value of `["TEST"]`, the validation fails.

```bash
$ terraform plan -var 'list_of_strings=["TEST"]'
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

╷
│ Error: Invalid value for variable
│
│   on variables.tf line 1:
│    1: variable "list_of_strings" {
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.list_of_strings is list of string with 1 element
│
│ list_of_strings must contain only alphanumeric strings (case-insensitive).
│
│ This was checked by the validation rule at variables.tf:5,3-13.
```

I've also tried specifying the value through `terraform.tfvars`, but the result stays the same. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two issues here seem to be that your outer wrapped `can(all())` function was probably intended to actually be a `alltrue()` function. Additionally the regexp character `*` was probably intended to be a `+` character:

```
condition = alltrue([
  for value in var.list_of_strings : can(regex("^[A-Za-z0-9]+$", value))
])
```

Additionally you could substitute `\\w` for the `[A-Za-z0-9]` if you want to clean it up somewhat (TF DSL requires double escapes on those characters).

Comment: The `alltrue()` solved the validation issue. Thanks, also for the other suggestions.